# List customers that have bought the same pair of products MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have the following two tables:

**customer**

```
id  | customer
----|---------
1   | john
2   | jenkins
3   | jane
4   | janet
5   | jenny
```

**products**

```
customer_id | product | price
------------|-----------|-----
        1   | brush     | 3.5
        1   | deoderant | 1
        1   | soap      | 2.5
        2   | bread     | 3
        2   | brush     | 3
        2   | soap      | 2.5
        3   | brush     | 3
        4   | deoderant | 1
        4   | soap      | 1
        5   | milk      | 1
```

So I have to find the pair of customers that have bought the same product and I must remove the duplicate pairs and remove the pairs such as (john, john) for john. The MySQL query that I create is:

**select A.customer, B.customer, products.customer_id, products.product  from customer A, customer B, products where
B.id = products.customer_id and A.customer <> B.customer group by B.customer;**

I get the following resulted:

```
customer|customer|customer_id|product   
--------|--------|-----------|--------
john    | jane   | 3         | brush
john    | janet  | 4         | deoderant
john    | jenkins| 2         | bread
john    | jenny  | 5         | milk
jenkins | john   | 1         | brush
```

I have been battling with this the whole morning and am I am stuck. I know that it is wrong because jane and jenkins bought the same item.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the result that you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way, that puts the customers into one column:

```
select p.*,
       group_concat(distinct c.customer) as customers
from customers c join
     products p
     on c.id = p.customer_id
group by p.id;
```

If you actually want pairs:

```
select c.id, c.customer, c2.id, c2.customer,
       p.product
from customers c join
     customers c2
     on c.id <> c2.id join
     products p
     on c.id = p.customer_id join
     products p2
     on c2.id = p2.customer_id and
        p.id = p2.id;
```

You might want `select distinct`, if customers could purchase the same product more than one.

Comment: Gordon there is a sytax error on second join (join on) which I can not fix in MySQL due to my inexperience, @Simone, yes customer_id is not really necessary but I wanted to see the numbers so I could see who is who in the products table.

Comment: @Dino . . . I kept rearranging the tables and seemed to have left in an extra `join`.

Comment: It seems to be working, Thanks. Although I think you mean p.id to be p.product?

Comment: @Dino . . . In the first query, I use `p.id` because that is (presumably) a unique key on the `product`.  This is a concept called functional dependency and that allows the `group by` to not include all the other columns (according to the ANSI standard).